# ANTLR how to evaluate ifdef else end statement

Tags: antlr, conditional-compilation

I would like to know how to evaluate ifdef ... else ... end statement which could be put anywhere in a code. I start with a simple example who implement 2 basic function add(p1,p2) and diff(p1,p2) where p1 and p2 are Strings. It only adds a + or a - in between p1 and p2. Here is my grammar:

```
grammar ifdef;

options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens 
{
    EQUAL           = '=' ;
    HASH            = '#' ;
    DBLEQUOTE       = '"' ;
    SEMICOLON       = ';' ;
}


@header {
    package Grammar;

    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.HashMap;

}

@lexer::header {
    package Grammar;    
}

@members {
    private Map<String, String> strMapID = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> strMapDefine = new HashMap<String, String>();
}


rule returns [String strEval]
    :   {   StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(); }
    (   command
        {   if ( $command.str != "" ) {
                strBuilder.append( $command.str );
                strBuilder.append( "\n" );
            }
        }

    )+ EOF
        { $strEval = strBuilder.toString(); }
    ;

command returns [String str]
    :   define      { $str=""; }
    |   undef       { $str=""; }
    |   set         { $str=""; }
    |   function    { $str = $function.str; }
    |   ifdef       { $str=""; }
    ;

define
    :   HASH 'define' ID
        { strMapDefine.put($ID.text, $ID.text); }       // save define ID into hash table
    ;

undef
    :   HASH 'undef' ID
        {   if ( strMapDefine.containsKey($ID.text) ) {
                strMapDefine.remove($ID.text);          // undef ID in hash table
                }
        }
    ;

set
    :   'set' ID EQUAL string SEMICOLON
        { strMapID.put($ID.text, $string.text); }       // save ID,string definition into hash table 
    ;

string
    :   DBLEQUOTE expr DBLEQUOTE
    ;

function returns [String str]
    :   add     { $str = $add.str; }
    |   diff    { $str = $diff.str; }
    ;

add returns [String str]
    :   'add' '(' p1=param ',' p2=param ')'
        {   StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.append( $p1.str );
            strBuilder.append( "+" );
            strBuilder.append( $p2.str );
            $str = strBuilder.toString();
        }
    ;

diff returns [String str]
    :   'diff' '(' p1=param ',' p2=param ')'
        {   StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.append( $p1.str );
            strBuilder.append( "-" );
            strBuilder.append( $p2.str );
            $str = strBuilder.toString();
        }
    ;

param returns [String str]
    :   ID          { $str = strMapID.get($ID.text); }      // assign ID definition to str
    |   string      { $str = $string.text; }
    |   function    { $str = $function.str; }
    ;

ifdef
    :   {   Boolean bElse= false;
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(); }
        HASH 'ifdef' '(' ID ')' c1=expr ( HASH 'else' c2=expr { bElse= true; } )? HASH 'end'
        {   if ( strMapDefine.containsKey($ID.text) ) {
                strBuilder.append($c1.text);
            }
            else {
                if ( bElse ) {
                    strBuilder.append($c2.text);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("ifdef content is : " + strBuilder.toString() + "\n" );
        }
    ;

expr
    :   .+
    ;

ID
    :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
    ;

WS
    :   ( ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

and java main class

```
package Grammar;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException;
import org.antlr.runtime.TokenStream;

import Grammar.ifdefParser.rule_return;


public class mainifdef {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RecognitionException {
        CharStream stream=null;
        try {
            stream = new ANTLRFileStream("src/input/test.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ifdefLexer lexer = new ifdefLexer(stream);
        TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ifdefParser parser = new ifdefParser(tokenStream);
        rule_return evaluator = parser.rule();

        System.out.println("Parsing Tree is \n" + evaluator.tree.toStringTree() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Evaluation is \n" + evaluator.strEval + "\n");

    }
}
```

With input file content like:

> #undef Z
>   set AB = "toto";
>   set CD = "titi";
>
> diff(CD,"essai")
>   #ifdef(Z) add( #end
>
> add ( AB , diff( CD,"essai") )

The result console is as expected

> ifdef content is :
>
> Parsing Tree is
>   # undef Z set AB = " toto " ; set CD = " titi " ; diff ( CD , " essai " ) # ifdef ( Z ) add ( # end add ( AB , diff ( CD , " essai " ) )
>
> Evaluation is
>   "titi"-"essai"
>   "toto"+"titi"-"essai"

My question is how to do to evaluate such input text which should give same result :

> #undef Z
>   set AB = "toto";
>   set CD = "titi";
>
> diff(CD,"essai")
>   #ifdef(Z) add( #end
>
> add ( AB , #ifdef(Z) add( #else diff( #end CD,"essai") )

The result console is (which is normal ANTLR behavior):

> ifdef content is :
>
> src/input/test.txt line 8:11 no viable alternative at input '#'
>   src/input/test.txt line 8:43 missing EOF at 'CD'
>   ifdef content is : diff(
>
> Parsing Tree is
>   # undef Z set AB = " toto " ; set CD = " titi " ; diff ( CD , " essai " ) # ifdef ( Z ) add ( # end add ( AB , < unexpected: [@59,94:94='#',< 6 >,8:11], resync=# > < missing ')'> # ifdef ( Z ) add ( # else diff ( # end < missing EOF >
>
> Evaluation is
>   "titi"-"essai"
>   "toto"+null

Some guidance where to start will be much more appreciate
Regards JPM

Comment: Thanks Bart to point out this. I'm more familiar with C/C++. I did your test an read some more explanation on java Class String. I will replace by : if !$command.str.equals("") ...

Comment: Indeed, that is correct. So, after changing that, does it still not work?

Comment: Yes, still not work. This was only to remove from output commands not to be evaluated. My concern is how to implement evaluation of ifdef statement. The grammar could not (I think) include every possibilities where an ifdef block could be find. I think to do what I'm looking for I will have to override ANTLR errors / token recognition but I didn't find yet where to start. Issue I face is that the expression in an ifdef statement could be an invalid rule until it is evaluated and replaced. I've read your blog but as far I understand this case is not treated.

Comment: I don't recommend parsing and evaluating in one go (as you're doing now). You might be able to do so for a trivial expression grammar/evaluator, but as soon as constructs like `if` come into play, it's (IMHO) better to first build an AST and then walk/evaluate said tree. You mentioned my blog, so I'll suggest you try to do something similar as I describer there. Best of luck!